# "Unrecognized token 'com': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')"

Tags: java, android, json, string-conversion, jsonexception

I have converted this json to string to save in local database

```
{
        "type": "file",
        "id": "b665ff0b-5f7b-4991-ae88-ac5054880223",
        "link": {
            "href": "https://s3-eu-west-com/87e9edff-e7bd-49ea-aa7a-8948cac29bc1/b665ff0b-5f7b-4991-ae88-ac5054880223.jpg"
        },
        "file_name": "sony 431.jpg",
        "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
        "file_size": 66727,
        "public": true,
        "meta": {
            "dimensions": {
                "width": 1500,
                "height": 1500
            },
            "timestamps": {
                "created_at": "2018-01-22T11:07:35.527Z"
            }
        },
        "links": {
            "current": "https://api.e-com.com/v2/files/b665ff0b-5f7b-4991-ae88-ac5054880223"
        }
    }
```

When I am using that string by converting into JSON I am getting error saying

> "Unrecognized token 'com': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')"

How can I resolve that error?

This is how I converted this json into string:

```
staticFile1.setFile(file.toString());
```

And string to json:

```
File file1 = new ObjectMapper().readValue(file, File.class);
```

Comment: please post your code how did you convert..

Comment: @SantanuSur i have added the code

Comment: Smells like missing `toString()` override but without seeing the code, it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are getting an error like this

> Unrecognized token 'com': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n
>   at [Source: (String)\"com.jwt.secured.user.ApplicationUser@6d9cce48:
>   Username: justiuser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true;
>   AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true;
>   AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities\"; line: 1,
>   column: 4]",

The com is related to the package reference in the string. Give a proper `toString()` implementation in the class and use `ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString` to converto to String.